# If statement in Excel with Len and some other snazzy code

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have 4 columns (c,d,e, & f) that I am trying to combine into column a.  Sometimes only 2 columns are filled out and other times all four have data.  My main issue is that what I want to go into column **A** CANNOT exceed 200 characters.  If it does, I need the rest of it to be placed into column **B**.  If it does exceed 200 characters, I need it to dial back to the last instance of **;**.  Can this be done in Excel?

These fields have email addresses in them for my companies database.

Comment: Is it about concatenating string ? .. in VBA ?

Comment: I don't know.  Can you give me some options to look up or try?  I am trying to do it all in Excel if possible.  Do you think I need to go with VBA?

Comment: every column contain only 1 email address ? .. if not what's separating each email address ?

Comment: There can be 0, 1, or several email addresses in each column. I need to seperate the field concatenations with ; if they are not empty.

Comment: Have you try Joseph4tw's updated answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

EDIT: made to handle the ';' character. It's not exactly at 200, but should get you close in most instances.

A1 formula:

```
=IF(LEN(CONCATENATE(C1,D1,E1,F1))>200,LEFT(CONCATENATE(C1,D1,E1,F1),FIND(";",CONCATENATE(C1,D1,E1,F1),170)),CONCATENATE(C1,D1,E1,F1))
```

B1 formula:

```
=IF(LEN(CONCATENATE(C1,D1,E1,F1))>200,MID(CONCATENATE(C1,D1,E1,F1),FIND(";",CONCATENATE(C1,D1,E1,F1),170)+1,LEN(CONCATENATE(C1,D1,E1,F1))),"")
```

Copy down

Comment: You beat me to it ! +1 this is almost exactly what I had, character for character.

Comment: :) wow, I usually don't make it first in these forums lol

Comment: It's email addresses .. you can't just cut in the middle to another cell !

Comment: There's always a critic :) lol let me see what I can do

Comment: @matzone edited the answer. hope that works well

Comment: My problem is that when I use the code above from @joseph4tw is there is not ';' separator between field c1 and d1.  Actually this is the case between all fields.  Any thoughts to this?

Comment: @JonathanMorningstar I thought you said that only the `A` column could be up to 200 characters max, then the rest would go into column `B`? These formulas do that, no?

Answer (score 2):

You can try joseph4tw's answer .. or you can try this VBA

```
Sub ConcatAddr()
Dim s As String
Dim n, x, x2 As Integer

For x = 1 To 10 '--> you can change this
  'concat all first
  s = Cells(x, 3) & _
      IIf(Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, 4)), ";" & Cells(x, 4), "") & _
      IIf(Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, 5)), ";" & Cells(x, 5), "") & _
      IIf(Not IsEmpty(Cells(x, 6)), ";" & Cells(x, 6), "")

  If Len(s) > 200 Then
    For x2 = 200 To 1 Step -1
      If Mid(s, x2, 1) = ";" Then
        Cells(x, 1) = Mid(s, 1, x2 - 1)
        Cells(x, 2) = Mid(s, x2 + 1)
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
  Else
    If Len(Trim(Replace(s, ";", ""))) > 0 Then
      Cells(x, 1) = s
    End If
  End If
Next
End Sub
```